# Löwenheim number of $L_{\kappa, \lambda}$

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

Just to clarify, I don't mean the Löwenheim-Skolem number as it's found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim_number), but rather the name given, for instance, on one of the axioms of abstract elementary classes: a cardinal $\kappa$ s.t. one has $X \subseteq B \prec A$, $\lvert B \rvert \leq \lvert X \rvert + \kappa$.

I don't have much familiarity with infinitary logics so I'd like to ask for a resource on Löwenheim Numbers for $L_{\kappa, \lambda}$, considering some multi-sorted signature/vocabulary of a given arity and cardinality (assuming they exist, of course, and with possible changes on the above inequality). I tried searching on the internet but couldn't find anything that wasn't about second-order logic. I also tried thinking about a "standard" approach (Tarski-Vaught test) but I'm not very confident on the argument (and the cardinalities involved) I came up with, so I'd like to see a result like this in the literature.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

Here's my attempt with cardinal arithmetic: Fixing a signature of arity $< \lambda$ and cardinality $\gamma$, we consider the case of the logic $L_{\kappa, \lambda}$.

First for terms, at level $0$ we have either a variable of some sort ($\gamma$ options, so we have enough variables, and we'll add new variables on the fly) or some element of $\lvert X \rvert$. At the first step, we have $\gamma$-many functions of a given arity $< \lambda$, so an upper bound is $\gamma \cdot (\gamma + \lvert X \rvert)^{< \lambda}$. Applying this again, we get $\xi^\alpha$, with $\xi = \gamma + \lvert X \rvert$, where $\alpha = <\lambda$ or $\lambda$ depending on whether $\lambda$ is regular or not.

Now, to the formulas, at level $0$ we have $\gamma$-many relations with their arities $< \lambda$, so we use same arithmetic and the bound stays at $\xi^\alpha$ in this case. For quantification, we have a choice of variables so we get $2^{< \lambda} \cdot \xi^\alpha = \xi^\alpha$ options. As for disjunction/conjunction, we have at most $(\xi^{\alpha})^{< \kappa}$ options. Since $\kappa$ is regular at successive steps that bound will stay the same. This completes the counting of formulas and witness formulas.

Now, we need $\lambda$ steps so we can use the Tarski-Vaught argument, but the bound stays the same at successor steps and limit steps, so we conclude that the upper bound for the size of the elementary substrucuture containing $X$ is

$$((\gamma + \lvert X \rvert)^{< \lambda})^{< \kappa} = (\gamma + \lvert X \rvert)^{< \kappa}$$ by the assumption $\lambda \leq \kappa$
or
$$((\gamma + \lvert X \rvert)^{\lambda})^{< \kappa}$$
which can be simplified to
$$(\gamma + \lvert X \rvert)^{\kappa}$$ or $$(\gamma + \lvert X \rvert)^{< \kappa}$$
whether $\lambda = \kappa$ or $\lambda < \kappa$, but the former is impossible because $\kappa$ is assumed regular.

Is everything correct? Is there a smaller bound?

Comment: Maybe if you post your argument (at least the cardinal arithmetic that you came up with), someone can check it.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Good suggestion, I've included my reasoning in an edit.